# iOS: TabController not showing with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabcontroller

I have an app with the start screen consisting of a table menu main which links to 4 different views, then three options to information pages.

Once on any of the main menu options are chosen, the view is shown with TabBar at the bottom of the main menu options. While the nav bar at the top has a back button leading to the main menu.

I built the storyboard which goes from a table view select to a single page.  After that was working and passing data, I embedded the single view into a Tab Bar Controller and added a second page.  It seems to be working as I would expect however the Tab Bar is not visible on the screen.

**Can please anyone help?**

I have added an image of the storyboard below:

[image: Storyboard Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the navigation controller. There is no deed for it so far. Make the tab bar controller your root view. 
If you need a navigation conroller within a certrain tab, or some or all of them, then add navigation controllers to those tabs (to the right in your storyboard).